# Set the last bin of histogram to a range to include all large values Seaborn, Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When there are outliers in a list of numbers, the last bins of its histogram are short and sparse. Thus, I want to have the last bin to use a range. For this example, it would be `10+` to include all values larger than 10.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
l = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,6,7,8,6,4,5,3,2,8,3,1,2,3,5,6,7,15,20]
sns.displot(l, binwidth = 1, kde=True, rug=False)
plt.show()
```

**The histogram of the list above**

[image: The histogram of the list above]

I haven't figured out how to do it with seaborn. If matplotlib would work, that is also terrific. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See e.g. [Matplotlib histogram with collection bin for high values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218704/matplotlib-histogram-with-collection-bin-for-high-values)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way, but you can rework a bit the data to [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) it to the desired value, and manually setting the xticks/xticklabels:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

l = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,6,7,8,6,4,5,3,2,8,3,1,2,3,5,6,7,15,20]

MAX = 10 # max value after which the data will be grouped

f = sns.displot(np.clip(l, 0, MAX+1), binwidth = 1, kde=True, rug=False)
f.ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, MAX+1)+0.5)
f.ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(1, MAX).tolist()+[f'{MAX}+'])
```

output:

[image: clipped histplot]

Comment: did it solve your problem?